# What does CUSTOMTAB_IS_INCOMPLETE mean?

Tags: error-handling, docusignapi

I am getting the following error:

> error calling webservice, status is:400 error text is --> { "errorCode": "CUSTOMTAB_IS_INCOMPLETE", "message": 
>       "A Custom Tab is not Complete. A Custom Tab requires both a Name and a TabLabel. 
>       Radio tabs may only have one radio selected in a group." }

I have many templates with many many radio buttons on them that have been grouped.

Occasionally, I get this error, which clearly means the template being called has an issue with one of the radio groups. However, I am not certain what the exact issue is?

Can someone shed some light on the meaning of this error? I believe all the names and Tab labels are correct and the Radio tabs are set by default to accept only one selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"• There is a provision for creating custom tab. But in case of custom tab both the attributes 
Name and TabLabel should be specified. If only one of the attribute is specified in the Tab 
element then an exception “CustomTab_Is_Incomplete” is thrown."

[Here](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf) is a (hopefully) helpful link to look at.